# Проблема с записью в XML-файл

Tags: xml, android, java

Здравствуйте! У меня есть XML файл, который содержит некоторые данные и находится в res/xml, и есть функция, которая которая должна этот файл пересоздать с новыми данными. Вот код функции:

```
void ListToXml() throws IOException {         
   XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

   serializer.setOutput(writer);
   serializer.startDocument(null, true);
   serializer.startTag(null, "root");

   for (int i=0; i<tovarList.size(); i++) {
       serializer.startTag(null,"element");
       serializer.endTag(null, "element");
   }

   serializer.endTag(null, "root");
   serializer.endDocument();

   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
           openFileOutput("res\\xml\\about_tovar.xml", MODE_PRIVATE)));
   bw.write(writer.toString());
   bw.close();  
 }
```

Проблема с записью, ошибок нет, но и файл не создается. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете писать файл в /res. И даже в /assets.

Используйте хранение в Internal/External storage.